# DataStudio: Get Date Range

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I'm trying to calculate an average per day within Data Studio. This should be based off the selected date range.

Is there any way to get the currently selected date range?

So, if "last 30 days" is selected: 30, last quarter: 90 etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of selected date range, you can use `count(Date)` in metric.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
However, I get the following error:
Unknown dimension or metric ID: t0.DATE. 

And I can't count the Dates within my sheet as not every day has an entry, so that count would be off.

Comment: This is completely incorrect. The question is asking for the number of days in the *selected date range* but your answer gives the number of days in the data. If you are lucky enough to ALWAYS have data for every day in the date-range then it will happen to be correct. But if you don't, or there's a possibility you don't, or data filters, tables or dimensions might mean you don't... then this answer will give a completely incorrect value.